# Template argument deduction and const qualification

Tags: c++, templates

Could anyone explain why the code does not compile.

```
template<class T, class DER>
struct Base {
  T a;
  Base(const T argB) : a(argB){}
};

template<class T>
struct Derived : Base<T, Derived<T> > {
  Derived(const T argD) : Base<T, Derived<T> >(argD){}
};

int main() {
  int val = 10;
  const int *p = &val;
  /* this was in the original question
  Derived<int*> d(p); // breaks, but compiles with Derived<const int*> d(p);
  */
  Derived d(p); // fails, but Derived<const int*> d(p); compiles
}
```

The error message is that about no conversion from `int*` to `const int*`. As I see it `T` can be substitues by `int*` and in that case the constructor to `Derived` receives its argument as a `const int*` and invokes the base with `const int*`. Why then is the constant qulaification getting lost.

I clearly do not understand how template argument deduction works. I have not been able to find any lucid but rigorous and exhaustive description of how it works when `const`, `*` and `&` are in play. That is, what will `a`  get type deduced to in these various cases.

```
 Foo(T& a)
 Foo(T  a)
 Foo(T* a)
 Foo(const T a)
 Foo(const T*a)
 Foo(const t&a)
```

when `a` is

- an object,
- a pointer and
- an array.

Comment: I do not understand the last part of your question. I assume you mean all those `Foo`s to be part of some class with some templated type `T`, but what don't you understand about them?

Comment: @DavidBrown I changed the wording a bit, hope its clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no template deduction in your example. `Derived<int*> d(p);` specifically sets the template parameter to `T` to `int*` (*pointer to int*). Your derived constructor takes a `const T` parameter which is a *const pointer to int* in this case. I think your confusion is because `const int* p;` does not declare a *const pointer to int*, but instead declares a *pointer to const int* which is not, and cannot be converted to, a *const pointer to int* (the former lets you modify the pointed to value while the latter does not).

Remember that C  and C++ declarations are generally read from the variable name outwards, so for `const int* p` you start at `p`, go left and see `*` and then go farther left and see `const int`, so `p` is a pointer to a const int. [Here](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/CS652/How+To+Read+C+Declarations) is a good guide on deciphering C declarations and [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) is also a very useful tool.

The problem with your example is `p` is a *pointer to const int*, but the constructor of `Derived<int*>` takes a *const pointer to int* since `T` is `int*`. This may seem confusing, but you can think of `const` as having a higher precedence than `*` in type declarations. So in `const int *` the `const` applies to `int` and then `*` applies to the whole thing making `p` a *pointer to const int* whereas for `const T`, the const applies to `T`, which is actually `int*` so `const T argD` makes `argD` a *const pointer to int*.

Using this same idea all your `Foo` examples can be easily deciphered.

```
Foo(T& a)       // a is a reference to a value of type T
Foo(T  a)       // a is a value of type T
Foo(T* a)       // a is a pointer to a value of type T
Foo(const T a)  // a is a constant value of type T
Foo(const T* a) // a is a pointer to a constant value of type T
Foo(const T& a) // a is a reference to a constant value of type T
```

In general only `Foo(T a)` and `Foo(const T a)` cannot be overloaded because it doesn't matter to the caller whether the argument is copied into a constant variable or not.

More specifically, if `T` is `char *` (pointer to char)

```
Foo(char *&a)       // a is a reference to a pointer to a char
Foo(char *a)        // a is a pointer to a char (*)
Foo(char **a)       // a is a pointer to a pointer to a char
Foo(char *const a)  // a is a constant pointer to a char (cannot overload with (*))
Foo(char *const *a) // a is a pointer to a constant pointer to a char
Foo(char *const &a) // a is a reference to a constant pointer to a char
```

If `T` is `const char*` (pointer to a const char) things are much the same

```
Foo(const char *&a)       // a is a reference to a pointer to a const char
Foo(const char *a)       // a is a pointer to a const char (*)
Foo(const char **a)       // a is a pointer to a pointer to a const char
Foo(const char *const a)  // a is a constant pointer to a const char (cannot overload with (*))
Foo(const char *const *a) // a is a pointer to a constant pointer to a const char
Foo(char *const &a) // a is a reference to a constant pointer to a const char
```

If `T` is `char* const` (const pointer to a char) then all the `const T` overloads are redundant because `const T` is equivalent to `T` when `T` is already const.

```
Foo(char *const &a) // a is a reference to a const pointer to a char (+)
Foo(char *const a)  // a is a const pointer to a char (*)
Foo(char *const *a) // a is a pointer to a const pointer to a char (^)
Foo(char *const a)  // a is a const pointer to a char (same as (*))
Foo(char *const *a) // a is a pointer to a const pointer to a char (same as (^))
Foo(char *const &a) // a is a reference to a const pointer to a char (same as (+))
```

Comment: Indeed. In my actual code the `<int*> wasnt there. I added it in to state that if I replace it with <const int*> it compiles. Since its confusing. I am editing it out.

Comment: @san left out the fun ones: `const int* const p` : a const pointer to a const `int` (can modify neither the pointer nor the value it points to), and the double pointers and pointer-refs such as `const int* const& rp` (easy), or my personal favorite, `const int* const int*& rpp` (not as easy).

Comment: @san perhaps you could provide a specific case you don't understand. In the cases you've mentioned you can just replace 'T' with the specific object or pointer type.

Comment: @san I've updated my answer to try and address your comment, but this sounds like something for a separate question. In general templated containers are not designed to take constant template paramaters (for example a `std::vector<const int>` will not compile).

Comment: If you could explain what hapens when `a` is a pointer, pointer to a const and a const pointer, that would be very helpful. I have already accepted your answer though.

Answer (score 5):

Because the constructor of `Derived` is `Derived(const T argD)`, so in your case it is `Derived(int * const)`. This does not accept an `const int*`.

A *"const (pointer to int)"* is not a *"(pointer to const int)"*.

Comment: Oh thanks I didnt know that such a declaration makes the pointer constant and not the pointee.  Is there a way to ensure that the constructor accepts const pointees *only*. Apologies for the terminology. If you also could adress my other questions I would gladly accept this answer. Just a pointer (no pun intended) to a good (reasonably comprehensive but not inpenetrable) resource would be fine

Comment: If you want to restrict to const pointees, the best thing to do is to declare the constructor as `Derived(const T* argD)`, and expect the user of the class to provide `T` rather than `T*` as the template argument.

Comment: @TylerMcHenry If I want the class to accept a pointer or a `std::iterator` I guess i should have two constructors, one with `const T* argD` and another with `const T& argD` ? and may be another if I also want it to accept arrays. And I found your coment helpful, if you can add it as an answer I will be able to upvote.